# Sending drawRect: to different instances of the same UIView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm Vattanak and I'm new to iOS development. I was wondering if it is possible to send two instances of the same subclass of UIView different drawRect: messages? If it's possible, please show me how. Thanks in advance!
In my AppDelegate.h:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
CGRect screenRect = self.window.bounds;
CGRect bigRect = screenRect;
bigRect.size.width *=2;

UIScrollView *scrView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
[self.window addSubview:scrView];

self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
self.array[0] = image1;
self.array[1] = image2;

for (int i=0; i<=1; i++) {
    BNRView *view = [[BNRView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    view.appDelegate = self;
    [view drawRect:view.bounds];
    [scrView addSubview:view];
    view.integer++;
    screenRect.origin.x += screenRect.size.width;
}

scrView.contentSize = bigRect.size;

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

and this is my UIView subclass header file:

```
@interface BNRView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) BNRAppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic) int integer;

@end
```

and my drawRect: method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [self.appDelegate.array[self.integer] drawInRect:self.bounds];
}
```

I want my two UIView subclass instances to draw the two different pictures above by fetching those images from the array. How do you do it? This is a small app that lets you swipe to change a pic from one to another, those pictures are drawn by my UIView subclass instances.

Comment: Can you make your question more clear ? I don't know what is "different drawRect: message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

Create a property on your UIView subclass which can access from where ever you want, set it and then drawRect accordingly.

Like:
In the header (.h) of your UIView subclass:

```
@property (assign) BOOL isGreen;
```

in the implementation (.m) of your UIView subclass:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    if (self.isGreen == YES) {
        // draw something in green: [UIColor greenColor]
    }

    else if (self.isGreen == NO) {
       // draw something in red: [UIColor redColor];
    }

}
```

Comment: This answer solves the problem in my simple app, thank you so much!

Comment: Bernhard I seem to have another problem. I created a few instances of my UIView Subclass using a for loop, but I can't send each of them a different drawRect:. Can you help me please?

Comment: Please add the code to your original question, you'll get much better answers from everyone including me and people  would stop down voting it.

Comment: Bernhard here is the update question, please kindly check it. Thanks!

Comment: Scrap all that drawRect approach and use UIImageView instead. There you can set the image directly in the for loop and add it to the scrollView.

Comment: Thank you very much Bernhard for introducing me to UIImageView class, now my app works as expected and the code is way much simpler than before, this is great!

Comment: You're welcome, it's an uphill battle at start, but then things fall into place quickly. You're using a BNR_ class prefix - if this is the prefix for Big Nerd Ranch, then you have the book(s), if not look the iOS Programming books from the Big Nerd Ranch up, they're pretty good.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm reading iOS programming book from Big Nerd Ranch and their explanation is easy to comprehend. I think it will be useful to finish this book first before starting to tackle a project on my own, but do you think this is a great idea to learn iOS programming? Any suggestion?

Comment: BNR is a good choice and I like the books by Erica Sadun too. When I did start, I also spent a lot of time http://www.raywenderlich.com and bought their books. You'll probably want to dig into: Marcus Zarra: CoreData, Nick Lockwood: iOS Core Animation and for a nice collection of many things: NSHipster. Read everything here too: http://www.objc.io

Comment: Ah thanks for your suggestion, but how long does it take in general to be fluent with all these things?